# Bootstrap-table sticky header doesn't move left/right with table content when scrolling

Tags: bootstrap-table

My table has frozen columns on the left and right. I have a sticky header as well, however when I add showFooter: true, the sticky header doesnt move left/right with the content when scrolling. When you scroll left or right you then have to stop and scroll a tiny bit up or down to get the sticky header to re-align with the content. Any fixes for this? I experience the same thing when I take the footer off but add a height to the table.

Answer (score 0):

im one of the three core develop of the bootstrap-table.
This is currently bug, i submitted a PR (https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/pull/5235) which fix the bug.

Example without the fix: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/UtechtDustin/4247
Example with the fix: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/UtechtDustin/4248

That means you can wait for the next version which includes the fix or you can apply the fix manually to your version (quite simple).

Comment: thank you! I don't see any difference in the code though, how can I apply the fix manually?

Comment: Check the diff of the PR (https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/pull/5235/files)

Comment: I'm using the unpkg links and I tried to replace the unpkg script tag with the update file and I get an error
Replaced this <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.0/dist/extensions/sticky-header/bootstrap-table-sticky-header.js"></script>

With this <script src="src/extensions/sticky-header/bootstrap-table-sticky-header.js"></script>

I have the file in that path exactly but I get this error:

Comment: bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at n (bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.min.js:10)
    at new n (bootstrap-table-export.min.js:10)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-table.min.js:10)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.js:136)
    at m.fn.init.t.fn.bootstrapTable (bootstrap-table.min.js:10)
    at buildTable (script.js:478)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (script.js:164)

Comment: https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/extensions/sticky-header/bootstrap-table-sticky-header.js would be the correct url, but this version dont contain the fix.
You have to wait for a new version!